# Android Emulator image Pixel and text very bad qulity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

i am using macOS 10.13.6 Mac mini (Mid 2011) intel processor. when i lunch a android emulator image qulity very bad and text regulation very bad

please anyone can help me??

[image: Android emulator picture and text regulation very bad]

[image: Android Emulator Pixel Not Clear when run on mac]

Comment: please check image attests and try to make solution

Comment: For reference on a 2012 MacBook Pro macOS 10.13.6, i7 8Gb with a Pixel 2 emulator image I'm seeing blocky text in the emulator both in and outside of tool window. Screenshots created by emulator look fine. You may want to try a device with a smaller screen size/number of pixels if blocky text bothers you.